# www.example.com gives 404 while example.com works perfectly

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a problem with Kubernetes deployment. My service works perfectly when accessing "example.com" or "https://example.com" but it does not work when accessing over "www.example.com" or "http://example.com" the default nginx backend shows up with a 404.

Here is my ingress implementation:

```
# Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
# make a new cert
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ${APP_NAME}
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: 'true'
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: ${APP_NAME}
            port:
              number: 80
  tls:
  - secretName: ${APP_NAME}
    hosts:
    - example.com
    - www.example.com
```

Here is my certificate configuration:

```
# Certificate
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: ${APP_NAME}
spec:
  secretName: ${APP_NAME}
  dnsNames:
  - example.com
  - www.example.com
  issuerRef:
    name: letsencrypt-production
    # We can reference ClusterIssuers by changing the kind here.
    # The default value is Issuer (i.e. a locally namespaced Issuer)
    kind: ClusterIssuer
    group: cert-manager.io
```

I configured the following DNS records:

```
example.com A 300 xx.xxx.xx.xx
*.example.com A 300 xx.xxx.xx.xx
www.example.com CNAME 300 example.com
```

Does anyone knows what could be the issue here? Every help is appreciated a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You need to map your ingress controller external IP to your domain as a DNS record:
it's present under your services

```bash
kubectl -n $NAMESPACE get svc
```

```bash
NAME                                     TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)                                 AGE
ingress-nginx-controller                 LoadBalancer   10.0.XX.XXX    XX.XXX.XX.XXX    80:XXXXX/TCP,443:XXXX/TCP              Xd
```

Add a DNS record in your DNS zone `example.com` ==> `$EXTERNAL-IP`

Answer (score 0):

the 404 was coming from Nginx. I'm not sure what went wrong but after reinstalling Nginx on my cluster it works now. I recommend everyone having this problem runing a curl -v and see if it is a redirect header or not.